# How to import an account in parity using CLI?

Tags: accounts, parity, import, cli

Here is what I tried:

```
 parity account new --chain dev
```

it creates new account and generates JSON file in 
`%HOME%\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\DevelopmentChain\`

So, then I cut the file from there and try to import it:

```
parity account import UTC--2017-05-14T22-02-46Z--717e724c-5bec-e5bb-1eb9-ab92354084b2 --chain dev
```

But I receive an error:

```
Importing accounts failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to import an already existing account? It's already available for your client. If not, please add more details to your question to outline your problem. Also, you need the full path for the import command unless you are in the same directory.

Comment: because I want to import it on my another computer that doesn't have this account. yes, I do use full path or make it local in the same directory. The quesion is How to use this command, is there a doc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is how to do it(Ubuntu):

```
mv ~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/DevelopmentChain ~/someFolder
cd ~/someFolder/DevelopmentChain
parity account import . --chain dev
```

Caveat: if you don't specify the chain, it will import to HOMESTEAD by default.

Answer (score 0):

yes, command `parity account import <PATH>`  the last argument should be a folder path, but not a file name.

once the keys are imported, parity will create new keys in `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/ethereum` by default.